# What is causing owner to display as UID instead of user name?

Tags: freebsd

When I create a user in FreeBSD using either `adduser` or `pw add user` the directory that the user is an owner of shows the owner as *UID groupname* instead of *username groupname*. Why is that? It is the only directory showing owner as a UID. Chown username:groupname makes no difference.

Edit:

I found out that UID is only displayed while using SFTP with FileZilla. Doing ls -l showed user name as owner. I tried disconnecting and reconnecting. No difference. So why would it show as UID one place and user name another?

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure what output you're referring to.

Comment: where the UID of the user is displayed?

Answer (score 1):

I use the convention of creating a group with the same name as the username for my users.

You can find the map of username to uid in `/etc/passwd`

```
# cat /etc/passwd
clan:*:2001:2001:Claus Andersen:/home/clan:/bin/sh
```

My uid is 2001 and my primary group (gid) is 2001

The map of gid to groupname is found in:

```
# cat /etc/group
clan:*:2001:
```

On FreeBSD you should never directly edit `/etc/passwd` as it is not the primary database. As you have done you should use `adduser` or `pw add user`. If you really want to edit `/etc/passwd` then use the `vipw` command as it will update the database properly.

Notice that /home usually is a symlink. With the above I get this result:

```
$ ls -l /home
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  8 Oct  4 12:34 /home -> usr/home

$ ls -l /usr/home
drwxr-xr-x  3 clan  clan  12 Oct  4 12:34 clan
```

Verify that `/etc/passwd` looks correct. If not then it is a simple user error. If the file however looks correct then use the `pwd_mkdb` command to update the passwd database to ensure consistency.

Another typical reason to see uid (and gid) on FreeBSD is if you're using Jails. If you have created a user/group on the jailhost and created files which are visible inside a jail - then you need to have the same user/group with matching uid/gid inside the jail.

Comment: Thanks for info. I don't edit passwd or group files directly. And i also use that same convention.